# Problems in running Hive queries

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have configured Hadoop and Hive on Windows through Cygwin.
But I am facing some problems like:

in hive terminal (CLI):

hive>

When I enter query, the query do not execute and terminal remains busy.

If I enter the query like:

```
bin/hive -e 'LOAD DATA INPATH 'kv1.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE pokes;'
```

### The Output is like this:

```
Hive history file=/tmp/Bhavesh.Shah/hive_job_log_Bhavesh.Shah_201111301549_1377455380.txt
FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:17 mismatched input 'kv1' expecting StringLiteral near 'INPATH' in load statement
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
bin/hive -e 'LOAD DATA INPATH kv1.txt OVERWRITE INTO TABLE pokes;'
```

without the single quotes around `kv1.txt`.

Comment: After entering the above syntax, the error is :                                                              FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:17 mismatched input 'kv1' expecting StringLiteral near 'INPATH' in load statement

log4j:ERROR Failed to rename [/tmp/Bhavesh.Shah/hive.log] to [/tmp/Bhavesh.Shah/hive.log.2011-11-30].

Comment: hey i just solved that issue by copying the kv1.txt in HDFS. But the problem is now that when I enter query of SELECT/INSERT using PARTITION field then I just get error like:                   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

Comment: @user1073129 That's great to hear you have a solution to your original problem.  I would recommend opening a new question for this new problem since it will be more visible to other users and the comments are not for asking new questions.

Answer (score 1):

If your file on the local file system try

```
bin/hive -e 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH kv1.txt OVERWRITE INTO TABLE pokes;'
```

By default it looks for the file in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

If your file on the local file system try

```
bin/hive -e 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH give absolute localpath OVERWRITE INTO TABLE pokes;'
```

If your file on the HDFS file system try

```
bin/hive -e 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH give absolute HDFS path OVERWRITE INTO TABLE pokes;'
```